# Cron Jobs Not working- Sugar CRM

Tags: cron, sugarcrm

I have set up cron jobs for my SugarCRM as requested by Sugar:

[image: Sugar CRM Scheduler Screenshot]

[image: Cpanel Screenshot]

But when we look at last runs it does not seem to work or show anything.

I am using this for email reminders, mail check and also scheduled campaign run.

Comment: @IsiahMeadows can i give you access

Comment: You might want to mask the URLs in your screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

- Is command-line `php` on your system installed and the executable in whatever PATH that cronjob is using?
  If not make sure to specify the full path, e.g. `/usr/bin/php` or `/usr/local/bin/php` are common.
  Also based on your operating system/distribution the php command line executable may have a different name, e.g. `php5`.
- Make sure to use the *web-process user*'s crontab or execute php with `sudo -u webprocessusername`, so that the cronjob will be executed with the correct permissions.
  Running the cronjob as different user or even *root* is usually *not* a good idea.
- To see potential error messages replace `> /dev/null` e.g. with `> /tmp/sugarcron.log` or `> /path/to/webfolder/sugarcron.txt` and check the file after a minute.

Further info on the SugarCRM Knowledge Base:

- [Introduction to Cron Jobs](https://support.sugarcrm.com/Knowledge_Base/Schedulers/Introduction_to_Cron_Jobs/)
- [Troubleshooting Cron and Schedulers](http://support.sugarcrm.com/Knowledge_Base/Schedulers/Troubleshooting_Cron_and_Schedulers/)

Comment: Its on a capnel server

Comment: @HassanWaqar Refer to the documentation of your cpanel webhoster (some have instructions in their wiki of how to run php in their cron) or consult their support.
Or just try `/usr/bin/php` and `/usr/local/bin/php` instead of just `php` and hope that you're lucky ;p
Also you could follow the `>` redirect advice from above and specify a location in your webfolder - then you can check the error message over the web. (Note: Sugar will block certain file extensions, `.log` is one of them)